# bulk_create for foreign key list giving unexpected output

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

bulk_create giving unexpected output , what is wrong here...????

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MessagePost(models.Model):
    send_to = models.ForeignKey(User)
    media_def = models.TextField(blank=True)
    message = models.TextField()

#userList fetched from db
userList = [User(first_name='a',last_name='b'),User(first_name='x',last_name='y')]

MessagePost.objects.bulk_create([MessagePost(send_to=u , media_def='media/images/1.png' , message='hai everyone') for u in userList ])
```

Here on using `bulk_create` it gives the following erroneous ***output*** :

```
TypeError : expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Also, just doing `User(first_name='a', last_name='b')` doesn't create the record. You still need to save it. You should use [`.create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#create) instead.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I believe the syntax here is valid; bulk_create operates on a list of model objects that have NOT been saved.  Your point re: the full traceback stands of course.

Comment: Oh, but now that I look at it again, it looks like it's only MessagePost objects that are being bulk created and they have foreign keys to User objects which are not yet created.  My mistake!

Comment: Yes :) - It only works with models of the same type, since it won't fire any `save()`s or deal with relationships, expecting it to save a related model and then enter the key reference is optimistic at best.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester you got it right but the userList is fetched from , db , sorry i didn't mention it,.,.